# Heat engine with three thermal baths

Tags: thermodynamics

I was wondering if we can surpass the efficiency of the Carnot engine with three thermal baths, so my question is:

Is the most efficient heat engine among three temperature reservoirs a cycle involving only adiabatic and isothermal processes? How would one show that?

Comment: Well, you could calculate it fairly directly.

Comment: @JonCuster by trying all possible processes?

Comment: Pick your favorite cycle (Carnot, Otto, whatever). Calculate efficiency using a cycle from T_hot to T_cold. Calculate for two cycles running from T_hot to T_warm to T_cold. Compare.

Comment: @JonCuster I cannot prove the statement by choosing three random cycles and comparing them because there is an infinite number of possible processes between two equilibrium points.